# How to change subcaption font size in Lyx?

Tags: fonts, lyx, subfloats, subcaption

I want to set the font for captions and sub-captions in my Lyx document to 'large'. There is no issues with changing size of captions, but I can't change sub-captions. Here are the preambles I try to use and the errors I get. The errors are not caused by 'caption' package. Here are two preambles that I tried to use.

With `subfigure` package:

```
\usepackage[large]{subfigure}
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=large,labelfont=bf, labelsep=endash]{caption}
```

With `subcaption` package:

```
\usepackage[font+=large]{subcaption}
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=large,labelfont=bf, labelsep=endash]{caption}
```

In both cases I receive following errors:

```
\begin{document}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

 \subfloat
               [ ---    ]{\begin{centering}
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
```

[Lyx MWE can be downloaded here](https://content.wuala.com/contents/riabovvv/Documents/Public/MWE/mwe.lyx/?dl=1&key=EEYAyx6Wz1iC).

[LaTex verson (I used Lyx option Export-> LaTeX(plain) to create it) can be downloaded here.](https://content.wuala.com/contents/riabovvv/Documents/Public/MWE/mwe.tex/?dl=1&key=EEYAyx6Wz1iC)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error by copying/pasting the preambles you've tried. Please provide a minimum working example.

Comment: @juliohm, link to MWE added to the question.

Comment: Can you add a link to the `.tex` file for those like me that don't have Lyx?

Comment: @karlkoeller, a link added in question.

Comment: @SS_Rebelious You can't use both `subfig` and `subcaption`. By the way, the `centering` environment doesn't exist; one should only say `\centering`.

Comment: @egreg, I know, I can't. I don't use them simultaneously. Don't know about `centering` environment. I didn't defined it manually - the code is generated by Lyx.

Comment: The error message you show probably comes from not loading `subfig`, as it is that which defines `\subfloat`. Does adding `[font=large]` to `subfig` (i.e. `\usepackage[font=large]{subfig}`) work?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. yes, it works, thank you. Add your comment as an answer plz.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message you show in your question comes from not loading `subfig`, as it is `subfig` that defines `\subfloat`. Adding `font=large` as an option to `subfig` should work (requires the `caption` package as well, I think), i.e.

```
\usepackage[font=large]{subfig}
```

And of course, remove the `subfigure` package from the preamble.